# Boot Camp: boot +option key does not show my usb (EFI) drive

Tags: boot-camp

I am trying to install Windows 7 SP1 Ultimate via Boot Camp and I've encountered several issues. Here's what I've encountered and overcome so far:

- Not getting USB Option in Boot Camp Assistant - fixed by editing plist
- USB Not showing up - tied three different flash drives w diff formats but no luck

I'm on OSX 10.10.1 Yosemite and my current flash drive is a sandisk 16gb formated w GPT (tried MBR too).

I've tried everything I can think of to this point including +option boot for the EFI / Windows option. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: I think I may have to go with burning a DVD to solve this one. I'm going to walmart to buy some blanks then I'll report back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading [a post on reddit about issues with boot camp and the usb install](http://www.reddit.com/r/osx/comments/2jbvuw/installing_windows_7_or_81_on_bootcamp_fails_on/) I found out that other people are having the same issue I'm having.

Anyway, burn your windows iso to a ***dvd*** and when bootcamp restarts your computer for the windows install use the ***+option*** key at boot as you would for EFI mode but instead select the dvd you just burned. This will install windows but you will need to reformat the bootcamp partition as ***NTFS*** for windows to install correctly. Once you are up and running make sure to open the flash drive you made and run the `setup.exe` file in the `BootCamp` folder on your `WININSTALL` USB.

## Make note that this only works for 64 bit version of windows